# Code is looped again and again

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
def begin_game():
    print "You landed on planet and see three rooms."
    door = int(raw_input("Pick number of door>>>"))
    print "You approach and see that you need to enter password..."
    password = raw_input("Enter your surname>>>")
    if door == 1:
        medical_room()
    if door == 2:
        library()
    if door == 3:
        basement()
    else:
        print "No room exists"
        begin_game()

begin_game()
```

When I enter `door` number, I get `medical_room` function done but then else statement is executed and code starts again over and over.

My question is why else statement is executed? Shouldn't it stop on if statement, execute inside block and stop?

Comment: As a side note, you generally do not want to call your function again like to loop back to the top. This way, you have potentially infinite recursion. Each time you call a function without returning, you build the stack 1 level higher, and when it gets to 1000 levels, it will quit with an exception. A better way to do this is to put the whole function inside a `while True:` loop, and have the non-error cases `break` or `return` (e.g., `if door==1: return medical_room()`, etc.).

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `elif` for the second and third if statements. `else` only considers the statement immediately before it.

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds. +1

Comment: I actually did not know it was limited to the first statement before it only.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `elif`, or else every time you input anything other than `3`, the `else` block will be executed, as `door != 3` and the `else` block only considers the preceding `if` or `elif` block.

```
def begin_game():
    print "You landed on planet and see three rooms."
    door=int(raw_input("Pick number of door>>>"))
    print "You approach and see that you need to enter password..."
    password=raw_input("Enter your surname>>>")
    if door==1:
        medical_room()
    elif door==2:
        library()
    elif door==3:
        basement()
    else:
        print "No room exists"
        begin_game()

begin_game()
```

Answer (score 3):

Or since it seems that you're looking for switch statement which does not exist in python you could do something like this:

```
rooms = {
    1: medical_room,
    2: library,
    3: basement,
}

chosen_room = rooms[door]

chosen_room()
```

Comment: This is probably the bet way to design this… except that you need to do something like `rooms.get(door, no_room_exists)` (with a `no_room_exists` function that handles the error), or a `try:`/`except KeyError:` to handle the error case in-line.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code tests the first if condition (door==1) and associated actions, then it tests the second and third if conditions. Since the third if statement is False (door==1), it will perform the else statement.

You should use elif statements instead of repeated if statements.

```
def begin_game():
    print "You landed on planet and see three rooms."
    door=int(raw_input("Pick number of door>>>"))
    print "You approach and see that you need to enter password..."
    password=raw_input("Enter your surname>>>")
    if door==1:
        medical_room()
    elif door==2:
        library()
    elif door==3:
        basement()
    else:
        print "No room exists"
        begin_game()
```